# Android Application Development with Visual Studio Using Java

Tags: android, visual-studio, ide

I want to develop android application with Visual Studio using Java Language. I know there are a lot of Plugins available for this purpose but all of them uses Native language for development like C#. Is there even a way to develop Android Application using Java?

Currently I am using Eclipse and I have tried other IDEs as well like IntelliJ IDEA.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to say that you have to drop your idea . Simply write them in Java using Eclipse. VS is not optimized for Java and Eclise has a larger ecosystem of useful plug-ins. Using VS for Android development is like designing a web-site with assembler: It is simply not made for that :). Eclipse is still best Ide for Android app development

Comment: I had to start using Android Studio because the last Ubuntu update broke the content assist in my eclipse with ADT and I'm very impressed. After more than 8 years using eclipse I didn't want to switch to another IDE, but Android Studio has made me want to. Give a more-than-five-minutes try ;)

Comment: It has also in my thinking that it would be better where google is the provider but i am waiting for full release .

Comment: There are plug-ins that do VS for Java (like you can write a Java based Minecraft mod in Visual Studio now, for example). -- also, Eclipse hasn't been supported for Android apps for a while now -- the official software is called Android Studio.